# MySQL Optimisation

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I have mysql-table called products with the following structure/contents:

```
id (int), public_id (int), deleted (bool), online (bool)
1         1                0               1
2         1                0               0
3         1                1               0
4         2                0               1
5         2                0               1
```

My question is, how to select all, currently online, not deleted products. In this example only record 5 (public_id 2). The same public_id means the same product (grouping) The higher the id, the newer the information (ordering). And the products need to be *not* deleted (where). And some other where statements, in this case with the online field.

I need all the aspects (grouping, ordering and where), but I can't figure out how.

Any suggestions?

Results of explain query from Galz:

```
id  select_type         table         type   possible_keys  key       key_len  ref    rows  Extra
1   PRIMARY             nomis_houses  ref    online         online    1        const  8086  Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  nomis_houses  index  NULL           house_id  4        NULL   9570  Using filesort
```

ps. This query did the trick, but is awfully, awfully, awfully slow:

```
select * from 
 (select * from 
  (select * from products order by id desc) tmp_products_1 
 group by public_id) tmp_products_2 
where deleted = '0' AND online = '1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on Sachin's answer and your comment, maybe this can help:

```
select * from products where id in 
(
   select max(id) as id from products
   where sum(deleted) = 0
   group by public_id
) 
and online = 1
```

**Edit by Pentium10**

The query can be rewritten into

```
SELECT * 
FROM   products p 
       JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id 
             FROM   products 
             HAVING  SUM(deleted) = 0 
             GROUP  BY public_id) d 
         ON d.id = p.id 
WHERE  online = 1
```

You need indexes on:

- (id,online)
- (public_id,deleted,id)

Comment: The `max(id)` is not allowed in the inner query. Inner query should only return one column.

Comment: @Galz - The result is correct, but also, too slow to be to any use. MySQL is already been busy with it for a couple of minutes.

Comment: @Tim - how big is the table? Can you post the explain for any of the suggested queries? (maybe the indexes can be improved...)

Comment: @Tim Could you please post the Explain extended output for this query. You might miss some indexes.

Comment: I updated the question with the results of the explain query, nothing fancy though. I'll try your solution now, @Pentium10 EDIT: there is no such thing as where sum(deleted), it should be `having` :-)

Comment: @Tim OK corrected, waiting for explain for the 2nd query and run time.

Comment: @Pentium10 - Thanks, that seem to do the trick. You can post it as an answer `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from products where public_id in 
(
   select public_id from products       
   group by public_id
   having sum(deleted) = 0
) 
and online = 1
```

Try if this works fine. The subquery gives all public_id which are not deleted, then run a additional filter for which are online.

Comment: Should be `group by public_id having sum(deleted) = 0` instead of the where + group by

Comment: Both solutions aren't sufficient. I edited the example, I added another record, also with public_id 2. The fifth row (latest version of public_id 2) should be selected instead of the fourth.

Comment: @Simen - Thanks. Edited my answer as per your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Well this *works*, but I don't know about its efficiency. Based on Sachin's answer

```
select p.* from products p where p.public_id in 
(
   select p2.public_id from products p2
   group by p2.public_id
   having sum(p2.deleted) = 0
) 
and p.online = 1 
and p.id = (select max(p3.id) from products p3 where p3.public_id = p.public_id);
```

Comment: It does work indeed, _but_ it's slow as hell :-) I started the query a minute ago, and it's still running as we speak. Isn't there a way to eliminate the queries in the WHERE-clause, because those are obviously the bottleneck? Perhaps I should consider a different approach to the table-structure? 3 minutes, and counting.